# javascript textbox validation in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript

I Want To Validate A Textbox in asp.net With Javascript that does not allow White space at the Begining but allow space in between words like "hello World" But Not As " hello world" And also not allow More than 4 character including white space in between words

Comment: So where are you getting stuck. Simple run your JavaScript code when the form is submitted, and write code to test for these conditions.

Comment: Use CustomValidator..

Comment: What does not allowing "more than 4 character including white space in between words" mean? What characters do you mean I can't include more than four of between words? Can I include special characters such as # between words, or does that count as a word? Does this no-more-than-4 limit apply to each gap individually, or can I have for the _entire string_ only 4 between-word characters, summing up all gaps together?

Answer (score -1):

"hello World" But Not As " hello world" use trim function 
 textbox.text.trim();